How to create a generic factory with injectable in Dart/Flutter?
I'm trying to come up with a scalable solution for factory registration in Dart/Flutter using injectable (or any other DI library).
Currently, I explicitly create a factory class (BarFactory) for each type (Bar), and call their create method (in Foo.doSomething) to create the instance (Bar):
import 'package:injectable/injectable.dart';

@singleton
class Foo {
  final BarFactory _barFactory;

  Foo(this._barFactory);

  void doSomething() {
    var bar = _barFactory.create();
    bar.blah();
  }
}

@injectable
class BarFactory {
  Bar create() => const Bar();
}

@injectable
class Bar {
  const Bar();

  void blah() {
    /* ... */
  }
}

The above dicatates writing a BarFactory for each Bar type. I can of course call getIt.registerFactory(() => Bar()) explicitly, but that's not much different from the above.
I tried to create a generic factory like this:
@injectable
class Factory<T> {
  final T Function() create;
  const Factory(this.create);
}

but that results in this error:
[SEVERE] injectable_generator:injectable_builder on lib/temp.dart:

Can not resolve function type
Try using an alias e.g typedef MyFunction = T Function();

which doesn't even make sense as T is a type parameter...
Any ideas on how to achieve this? I'm open to using a different DI library if it helps.

What do you think about code generation? I guess, since factories are pretty generic, this can be the case here.

@Sameri11 that's an eligible option if there's no simpler solution
